# Adding sleep command to spread server load

Tags: php, cron, debian

I have a Debian linux server that runs a large number of cron jobs via a 3rd party scheduler. Many of these cron jobs coincide at exactly on the hour xx:00:00 and half hour xx:30:00 which causes large spikes on the load.

While I am not observing any abnormal behaviour of the server, the more jobs that are added, the higher the load is becoming.

The jobs are small PHP CLI commands run locally on the server that take <30s to run.

I was thinking of adding random sleep xx; values to the beginning of each PHP CLI command of up to around 120s so that some of the commands are more spread out.

The current command launched is

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/test.php
```

which I was thinking of changing to, for example,

```
sleep 45; /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/test.php
```

My question is, is this just 'false economy' as once the command is loaded with the sleep xx; added to it, is it just wasting resource sitting there counting down and waiting to execute and should I take the approach of "if it ain't broke, don't try and fix it"? Is it better to just let the server queue up the commands and let it process them in due course?

Thank you.